# SharePoint 2013 - Extra HTML tags in JSLink Styling

Tags: sharepoint-designer, jslink

I'm customising my views using context jslink, it's going well but I noticed that in the code there are extra `<p>` tags and also a `<br>` being added neither of which should be there.

Does anyone know how or why this is?

Here is an example of rendered code from one of my views for an announcement list.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <p>Title</p>
    <div class="ExternalClass01D1F6DBE8E74AD88A09068277CCFDBB">
      We love it.
      <br>
      <p>​</p>
    </div>
      <p></p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The div with the external class has been added by SharePoint as has the `<br>` and the two `<p>` that follow.

Comment: Is the field render a Richtext /HTML field?

Comment: It says it's plain text....very odd.